# Block-sorting rows and columns in a 2D array

Tags: code-golf, array, sorting

Given a 2D array of integers, let's sort its rows and columns in blocks. This means that you only have to sort a given row or column, but applying the transformations needed for sorting it to every other row or column in the 2D array.

#### Rules

- Input will be a 2D array of integers and a 1-indexed integer. This integer will represent the row to be sorted if the number is positive, or the column to be sorted if the number is negative (or the other way round you want). Example: Given a `4x3` (rows x columns) array you can sort the second column with a `-2` argument or the third row with a `3` argument. This second argument will never be zero and its absolute value will never be greater than the corresponding dimension of the array.
- Output will be also a 2D array of integers with the needed transformations applied to sort the given row or column. Alternatively you can just write the array to STDOUT.
- The output array will have the specified row or column sorted in ascending order. Just note that when you need to swap two numbers in a row, the whole columns where the numbers lay will be swapped. And when you need to swap two numbers in a column, the whole rows where the numbers lay will be swapped.
- In the case in which the same number appears several times in the row/column to be sorted, there will be several solutions possible according to the way you swap the values, just do accordingly with the rest of rows/columns to be swapped.

### Examples

```
Positive indices for rows and negative indices for columns

[5  8  7  6                                  [1  3  2  4
 1  3  2  4   order by -3 (3rd column)  -->   9  6  3  0
 9  6  3  0]                                  5  8  7  6]

[5  8  7  6                                  [9  6  3  0
 1  3  2  4   order by -4 (4th column)  -->   1  3  2  4
 9  6  3  0]                                  5  8  7  6]

[5  8  7  6                                  [5  7  8  6
 1  3  2  4     order by 2 (2nd row)  -->     1  2  3  4
 9  6  3  0]                                  9  3  6  0]

[5  8  7  6                                  [6  7  8  5
 1  3  2  4     order by 3 (3rd row)  -->     4  2  3  1
 9  6  3  0]                                  0  3  6  9]

[1  2                                    [1  2     [3  2
 3  2]   order by -2 (2nd column)  -->    3  2] or  1  2]  (both are valid)

[7  5  9  7                                  [5  7  7  9     [5  7  7  9
 1  3  2  4     order by 1 (1st row)  -->     3  1  4  2  or  3  4  1  2
 9  6  3  0]                                  6  9  0  3]     6  0  9  3]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code for each language win!

Comment: This comes from [the sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16868/70347).

Comment: Can we change the integer representation? negative for rows and positive for columns?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz yes, that is stated in the question.

Comment: Can a row/column contain duplicated numbers?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen yes, see last examples and last point of the rules.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
function(x,n)`if`(n>0,x[,+x[n,]],x[+x[,-n],])
`+`=order
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCsMgEADvvsLjLllLU3ts85EgGJoVhGZT1IK/t0tPMzAwZST7cCN95dXyKdBJMOYUQZYr9ZWmvgqFoKpGTgIFNHGKz7PsXEbldqnMO8xouo7ssbWSO9Tt@LwZ5huS9WTvWk3Succ/nMfxAw)

Reassigns the `+` operator (actually a function in R) to the `order` function, which returns the indices of a vector from smallest to largest. Then it's just array manipulation.

Comment: [It's just as short as a recursive function :-)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172068/67312)

Answer (score 5):

### Matlab, <strike>73</strike> <strike>62</strike> 47 bytes

```
@(m,i){sortrows(m,-i) sortrows(m',i)'}{(i>0)+1}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z@mYKugp6f330EjVydTs7o4v6ikKL@8GMjTzdRUQHDVgbLqtdUamXYGmtqGtf/TNKJNFSwUzBXMrBUMFYwVjBRMrBUsFcyATINYHQVdY83/AA)

-11 bytes thanks to @Giuseppe.

-15 bytes thanks to @LuisMendo.

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 55 bytes

```r
f=function(m,i)"if"(i<0,t(f(t(m),-i)),m[,order(m[i,])])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc3LCsIwEIXhvU9RupqBU6hNvEHzFu5KFxoNDDgJhIj69LFSV99/VifXGlx4Rl8kRVIItxJakrFHoUCFlNEJM3RCyrd7Jp0EM89ctRm7Ri8ly5s87XDEAXtsYTDA4rS0Qc@IOb2cQfTp4Syun9888yYsZ535a1eHFcP1Cw)

Alternative to [ngm's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172063/67312); a recursive function which was inspired by [DimChtz's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172066/67312)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

*negative for rows and positive for columns*

```
>0?VñgUÉ:ßUa Vy)y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/387APuzwxvTQw51Wh@eHJiqEVWpW/v9vzBUdbapjoWOuYxarE22oY6xjpGMCZFnqmAHZBrGxCrpBAA)

Comment: This fails when `U` is negative - the previous 17 byte version works, though.

Comment: @Shaggy My bad, I though it would work anyway, didnt check at all

Comment: Not a bad idea, though, passing a function as the first argument of `ß` that automatically gets applied to `U`. It could create issues with trying to pass literal strings, but post a suggestion to the GitHub repo anyway for further investigation.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 90 bytes

```javascript
t=m=>m[0].map((_,x)=>m.map(r=>r[x]))
f=(m,k)=>k<0?m.sort((a,b)=>a[~k]-b[~k]):t(f(t(m),-k))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHNCoMwEITvPsUeE1jFv9a2VPsgIZRotbQaIxqKp766XfUs9OBlYWaZ@RL2rT5qKPpXZ93WPMppsqlOMy186WnVMXbHkZNeRJ9mvRgl506VMo01Leqrf9PeYHrLmMKcHCW@tXTzefKLZRWzTHN0a86nwrSDaUqvMU/yhQMgDggnhAThKHHWAUKEECLEqz7TZrF86UgENyK4s0NPvE9PuE/N1q8oFq6BOb2@fAtJMKJScfIXMqB7/AA)

#### How?

JS has no native transposition method, so we need to define one:

```javascript
t = m =>              // given a matrix m[]
  m[0].map((_, x) =>  // for each column at position x in m[]:
    m.map(r =>        //   for each row r in m[]:
      r[x]            //     map this cell to r[x]
    )                 //   end of map() over rows
  )                   // end of map() over columns
```

Main function:

```javascript
f = (m, k) =>         // given a matrix m[] and an integer k
  k < 0 ?             // if k is negative:
    m.sort((a, b) =>  //   given a pair (a, b) of matrix rows, sort them:
      a[~k] - b[~k]   //     by comparing a[-k - 1] with b[-k - 1]
    )                 //   end of sort
  :                   // else:
    t(f(t(m), -k))    //   transpose m, call f() with -k and transpose the result
```

*Example with \$k=2\$:*

$$M=\pmatrix{5&8&7&6\\1&3&2&4\\9&6&3&0}\rightarrow
t(M)=\pmatrix{5&1&9\\8&3&6\\7&2&3\\6&4&0}\rightarrow
f(t(M),-2)=\pmatrix{5&\mathbf{\color{red}1}&9\\7&\mathbf{\color{red}2}&3\\8&\mathbf{\color{red}3}&6\\6&\mathbf{\color{red}4}&0}\\f(M,2)=t(f(t(M),-2))=\pmatrix{5&7&8&6\\\mathbf{\color{red}1}&\mathbf{\color{red}2}&\mathbf{\color{red}3}&\mathbf{\color{red}4}\\9&3&6&0}$$

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
diø}Σ¹Ä<è}¹diø
```

Whopping -10 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*.

Uses a positive integer-input to sort the rows, negative for columns.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/JfPwjtpziw/tPNxic3hF7aGdIIH//3WNuaKjTXUsdMx1zGJ1og11jHWMdEyALEsdMyDbIDYWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/mpuSZV1BaYqWgZO/pYh@mpJCYlwJm6yj5l5ZAZSL/p2Qe3lF7bnHk4RabwytqI0Hc/7U6h7bZ/9c15oqONtWx0DHXMYvViTbUMdYx0jEBsix1zIBsg9hYLl0TgkqMCKogwhqQIYY6RkBBoCRQwBDIN9cx1bHUMceuBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
di }      # If the (implicit) integer input is positive:
  ø       #  Swap the rows and columns of the (implicit) matrix input
          #   i.e. 3 and [[5,8,7,6],[1,3,2,4],[9,6,3,0]]
          #    → [[5,1,9],[8,3,6],[7,2,3],[6,4,0]]
Σ    }    # Sort the rows of this matrix by:
 ¹Ä       #  Take the absolute value of the input
          #   i.e. -3 → 3
   <      #  Decreased by 1 to make it 0-indexed
          #   i.e. 3 → 2
    è     #  And index it into the current row
          #   i.e. [5,8,7,6] and 2 → 7
          #   i.e. [5,1,9] and 2 → 9
          #  i.e. [[5,1,9],[8,3,6],[7,2,3],[6,4,0]] sorted by [9,6,3,0]
          #   → [[6,4,0],[7,2,3],[8,3,6],[5,1,9]]
          #  i.e. [[5,8,7,6],[1,3,2,4],[9,6,3,0]] sorted by [7,2,3]
          #   → [[1,3,2,4],[9,6,3,0],[5,8,7,6]]
¹di       # And if the integer input was positive:
   ø      #  Swap the rows and columns back again now that we've sorted them
          #   i.e. 3 and [[6,4,0],[7,2,3],[8,3,6],[5,1,9]]
          #    → [[6,7,8,5],[4,2,3,1],[0,3,6,9]]
          # (And implicitly output the now sorted matrix)
```

Comment: I got `diø}Σ¹Ä<è]¹diø` which is a subset of yours, so I'm not posting a separate answer.

Comment: @Emigna Dang, you make it look so easy.. Now that I see it I can't believe I hadn't thought about that myself, but it's ingenious at the same time.. Thanks! A whopping 10 bytes saved thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
y0>XH?!]w|2$XSH?!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v9LALsLDXjG2vMZIJSIYyPr/X9eYK9pUwULBXMHMWsFQwVjBSMHEWsFSwQzINIgFAA)

Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L/SwC7Cw14xtrzGSCUiGMj6H6uuq6se4RJVEfJf15gr2lTBQsFcwcxawVDBWMFIwcRawVLBDMg0iOXSNcErbYRXloDRQM2GCkbWIIlYLkOuaHMFU6CsORa1AA)

#### Explanation

```
y       % Implicit inputs: number n, matrix M. Duplicate from below: pushes n, M, n
0>      % Greater than 0?
XH      % Copy into clipboard H
?       % If true
  !     %   Transpose matrix. This way, when we sort the rows it will correspond
        %   to sorting the columns of the original M
]       % End
w       % Swap: moves n to top
|       % Absolute value
2$XS    % Two-input sortrows function: sorts rows by specified column
H       % Push contents from clipboard H
?       % If true
  !     %   Transpose again, to convert rows back to columns
        % Implicit end
        % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 23 bytes

```apl
{⍺<0:⍉(-⍺)∇⍉⍵⋄⍵[;⍋⍺⌷⍵]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY89TsNAEIV7n2I67xQWXv/GgWOkQxRWkJGFJaOkiqJUoEAIi6DgAJyAykKi5ChzEfO8RtsgITejt/PmfTtT3jTB5aZs2qtg2ZTrdb3s5fmtbmX/ovsKdSvm6yycizmoAJLl4R5aTCfHO9TzUzFH9OXpE6@LXd8vxlAnh/cVpDzeVicYmPvttY@MX5V14w8J06123vdHrGT/qlKaUU4ZK00xRZSwKiiDDJkXg/@n7RJAJJMQLul8h4gmAVK4s9GP0LZ@jImQvWlHZBaQskosQLMKLaAYjhh3AJoVwu7s36enrZ1TSgXl/66Yg4eMpmQIg074hX8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>71</s> 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda m,n:n<0and sorted(m,key=lambda l:l[~n])or zip(*f(zip(*m),-n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZPRToMwFIbv9xQn8aYYSKAFJov6IqQXTFi2CO3SoWZe@Op4ehgTcBmY2aRAoRz@7/w/@2O91Yo3zeapzKp1nkHlqpV69DOVw0GbushZ5b4Wx@5xuSrTLyUdbeBzt2f3G0anynE95TjN3uxUDRuWppEL8IBziTOWeMBxBxMjDQAEAAcIF72b@LbAyXGG51La5IWB9RE8AUyYHF50@VYpB8DznnFHgt@lan6vVGLVnMr5UrqecKZVQYQoSGJBFotbES/qmkIMgYX1dox4sVu/EMP/RZyolUZUBovF1/l6eBwYx7wZ/XFGIzhOfNfg@DRbQkViu/9Gsrgji2aTnaI5JAs7suAK2Yxg@h1ZMiCzivjcONIvx9srm6WeIqKyAaIm/2Tx5NYoi5REidta5yQAW2uMbGYKeM/KXe70NdquWwcs9fIvuVqSocP1bDcCYMGhHrkhSHDriVUvaBEMezF2J5h2Jyal1iPZrf02jSO30CvsNarFTMbkfPMN)

---

If `n` is negative, the rows are sorted based on column `n`.

Otherwise the matrix is transposed, sorted the same way, and transposed back again.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
ZṠ}¡
çị@ÞA}ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/q4c4FtYcWch1e/nB3t8PheY61h5f///8/OtpUR8FCR8FcR8EsVodLIdpQR8FYR8FIR8EEzLUEioNFDGJj/xsDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 326 bytes

```java
(a,b)->{int l=a.length,w=a[0].length,k,m,t,i;if(b>0){for(i=0;i<w;i++){for(k=1;k<(w-i);k++){if(a[b-1][k-1]>a[b-1][k]){for(m=0;m<l;m++){t=a[m][k];a[m][k]=a[m][k-1];a[m][k-1]=t;}}}}}else{b*=-1;for(i=0;i<l;i++){for(k=1;k<(l-i);k++){if(a[k-1][b-1]>a[k][b-1]){for(m=0;m<w;m++){t=a[k][m];a[k][m]=a[k-1][m];a[k-1][m]=t;}}}}}return a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNc5swED03v2InJ6glwEmatJXxP2guOTIcBJZtgZBcSYRmGH67u3w4TtupDvD09q32ze5W/JVTcxK62tXnUnHn4AeXur8BkNoLu@elgOcecZZnOdjggjhBBEXIBpQ6z70s4Rl0CueAkyKk2zEHVMojJfTBH0mX8izJL7eaNMQTyeQ@KLZJ2O8NPp0mTG46JlermajTNas3QUdlyOqRRDXPCrrOsxo/2wvOZ3mD@c1GsWaUeizXjDG2/Jc7JrB3lHo2jEcoJ/ric0rX7GpE/WNE/WlkfGFygEbqGX000l2NYLQZy07/dMmcmRldjFjhW6uBs@HMsK@ntlDY16W9r0buoMHpBC/eSn3Ich72AHF89P7kvsdxaXbiYNQ@woSyFr/KI9cHEZWmiX@2wnlptIvXT3fJYxIXypQ1dcZ6fIla0znK9Y6WRrWNdlRqyundjnJr@Rs6mdYBrHCtmubPJm6@Qwo6soEWHSzb0U/R8fRfCHwl8ETgcSBXdk3gnsAdgYeP7DdUTYEE2U8DAfoQzoWmqaCBeTJz2WWVrlMaBRUKqkWQycu6sWrUvLw5L5rItD46Yf988C7Lqnx1C7e4zH9rlA7@x6Kx4WY4/wY)

Well guys, this question was very frustrating for me, and I posted my answer KNOWING I was forgetting something, luckily we have legends like [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen/%22Kevin%20Cruijssen%22) out here to help us out :)

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 281 bytes

```java
a->b->{int l=a.length,w=a[0].length,k,m,t,i;if(b>0)for(i=0;i<w;i++)for(k=0;++k<w-i;)for(m=0;a[b-1][k-1]>a[b-1][k]&m<l;a[m][k]=a[m][k-1],a[m++][k-1]=t)t=a[m][k];else for(b*=-1,i=0;i<l;i++)for(k=0;++k<l-i;)for(m=0;a[k-1][b-1]>a[k][b-1]&m<w;a[k][m]=a[k-1][m],a[k-1][m++]=t)t=a[k][m];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNb5wwEL3nV1g5VFBsYJM0aeuFS6VKPfSUI@JgvGbXYGyKTcgK8du3w8f2uxzMmzfP80YzrtgLI6YVujrUF66Ytegrk3q8Qcg65iRHFSjC3kkVlr3mThodft7AXmqX5VmO/yX6ZLTtG9Htv2gnjqJLU1Si5MJIWpB0hJtIJSxUQh/dCQ8Jy@L8GtW4wQ5LKkuvSGO/NJ0nk5jK/UBlECxxDXEQ1PuBSLoQDRAsK8guz2o40ivO3zR7BZlmxsn6hwQGFAQrTpzvtkxOhbICzQWLtwnZ4dVX/eWrfvedyyyG4FuvCHwHukTN7Lsomtl3RWC@@S4KOl0ozLztCwUz30b/YuQBNbAO79l1Uh@znPkjQlF0cq61H6OIm4M4GlWGcIHX4pWfmD6KkJsm@tYLO@/BRrunu/gxjgpleE2s6RxUIp0ZLGH6QLhRfaMtkZowcncgrOvYGTpBaFsuNADmryhBWgxXclwU8ze@w@g9Rk8YPU74J7vD6B6jO4wefmU/gGpJxNNEF7oMWduqs7ea@CHjXLTOIw/@lp93D29l3cOq2p7JspPxKqhAUG2CTF6fEq1mzfPZOtGEpndhC3N03g9ZVuXBLbr16fSnRmnvfyw0Nt1Ml@8)

Comment: I haven't looked at the actual algorithm yet, but you can save 35 bytes by removing all the brackets and putting everything inside the loops (including the inner if-statement). [Try it online: **291 byte**](https://tinyurl.com/y9x6qcg6) EDIT: [Here with space indentations](https://tinyurl.com/yakxhzcu) so you can more clearly see the changes I did.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I knew I was missing something

Comment: In addition, you can make it a currying input `a->b->` instead of `(a,b)->` and remove the `return`-statement, since you are modifying the input-array. [**281 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/yd5tsaxm) Still a nice answer, though. +1 from me. I did the challenge in 05AB1E, but wouldn't even have tried it in Java this time. ;)

Comment: [270 bytes](https://tio.run/##dVFLT4QwGLzvr2j2YCAUsur6SoGLiYkHT3skPRQsa6EtZCmiIfjX148CvuXS6cy0Q@cr2DPzq5rr4rE8ZpI1DXpgQveNYUZkqAA5aI2QQd7qzIhKB3czCIU2CU0o/sNzW@mmVfwQ3mvD9/wQx3l0ZH6c@nEPx5CMWCC53psn3EUs2dBlV2KFDRbRhojcSeONm1cHJ/V9IsKOCM@z@xJkzyvDzhfEEgoIlqQ0Kf1TGk@InqhQAqtGHE0rqBiQ5004Mq6ZFUq4bDiyadFbCnHyV5z8HjfeAEkQV44rxHXEYjXGWVWNcROCzDnOOshwJCuE6jaV0PJc9nMlHpGC9p2dOQi9Tyhze3AhNFcNIggvkebdQk36@PUX@Bpf4csBf1Kn@Byf4e1X6gZfArkZBmK5PGB1LV@d6WY3YFnGa@P4W3fW4b3jxOxIwsk1D8sW1C@GAgzFbEjEMlBSjJ7da2O4CqrWBDU8zDgftqSg3hqtXTL89Ejt/MfCjw2r4fgO "Java (OpenJDK 8) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 186 bytes

```cs
(x,y)=>{Func<int[][],int[][]>shift=a=> a[0].Select((r,i)=>a.Select(c=>c[i]).ToArray()).ToArray();return y>0?shift(shift(x).OrderBy(e=>e[y-1]).ToArray()):x.OrderBy(e=>e[-y-1]).ToArray();}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZRNj9MwEIbv@RWjnmzhRP1YWKAkCFaCC4gVReIQ5WBct2uRxovtlkZVfnuZJGy3SbZRhJiD5Y9nxvY7YwvrC23kcWtVtoZFbp3czL3zUfBJZb/mnudlfCPtPRcSbvRSftTpyjt4gCZSbi3cGr02fFPN1POlWcedErDTagmfucqIdQZjxwlws7b0xD16lPZhm4k3KnNxEicMsFM15SiCH6kWPxfaOAiPZM9yGkaHBv9A2ju1ciEPI@DxOAkWMpXCEWKYQhf@MBZhJGKV0OCbfmcMzwk9686NdFuTQR6N31bhSN3uafDFLKV5nxMZRjLO/Ukjwut9c91vAfPiiIqe33jHDSqCixBCJn/HSWO1qU5pyACKeIDnDF4yuGbwAgp2GZswmDGYMrjqxV5hnIoct7GideBbTKMj1ZFpa@lGZ1anMvhulJNYPZKM/JON6JOBTlmtQzLwZxTJIeDVQHA6kKs2boCNxPQlA1We9uo7q4ABwnavOf33Y2F1YJlgbq//d410qGKQxBN6qWa@Sr6sSuYsV8Ujem/UjjvZ@FbqPf6@@lqUS//KCr86Lu6AlM/N4J/Sxp9@bA03UboZ2oG6bp23QAQ8gxGMWnVY37HXsy1J16UXL7yiOP4B)

Ungolfed:

```cs
    private static int[][] Blocksort0a(int[][] array, int sortingInstruction)
    {
        Func<int[][], int[][]> shift = a => a[0].Select((r, i) => a.Select(c => c[i]).ToArray()).ToArray();

        sortingInstruction++;

        array = sortingInstruction < 0 ? 
        shift(shift(array).OrderBy(e => e[-sortingInstruction]).ToArray()) 
             : 
        array.OrderBy(e => e[sortingInstruction]).ToArray();

        return null;
    }
```

The shift function we'll use twice, so a function variable will save space. The function iterates through the horizontal dimension of the array on index, and adds every item on that index in of each horizontal array to a new output array (horizontally) - much the same as in Arnoud's JS solution.

Now the ordering is simple, order horizontal array by number-at-index (argument -1), optionally shifting the array before and after sorting.

Seen how the question talks about arrays specifically, we convert to array a few times (very, very wasteful). Feeling a bit silly to use such a verbose language in code golf hehe.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>142/139</s> 138/135 bytes (and yet another -1 by Kevin)

```cs
(a,s)=>s<0?a.OrderBy(e=>e[~s]).ToArray():a.Select(f=>a[s-1].Select((v,j)=>new{v,j}).OrderBy(e=>e.v).Select(e=>f[e.j]).ToArray()).ToArray()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZRLb9NAEIDv/hWjnHbFxmqSQoHWQVAJLlRUDRIHy4dlMwkujrfsbo2iyPz1MLbb1I/GshBzsPbxzXjnqexYaYP7exuna1hsrcPNuVff@Z/j9Ne553mp3KC9kwrhUi/xk05W3s4DEpVIa@Ha6LWRm/KkOi/EOuliBZmOl3Al45RZZ8h2GIE0a8sP3JNGIR/vU3URpy6MwkgALcpPsZvD90SrnwttHAR7JoXlwdxenLyT/hezRPNhyzCYY/jHRtz/qt8bI7eMv5X@AhNUjq2CuQzteBI9HrBM3JKJFH/vaJXzhhk/448cbVch@rd1s7XlniJU9yCThjykKwiAbIdR47bpbSHEAAVlBy8FvBZwJuAV5OI4NhEwEzAVcNqLvSE7JXnSxvLWg68pLY6VT@atq0udWp2g/83EDqkakI3GBxnxZw0dslSZFDCecSKHgKcDwelArvxxA2wkpi8ZFOVpb3xnJTAgsF03p//@LKoOKhPK7dn/rpEOlQ8K8YQfq5kblMuyZGq5yp/QOxNn0mFjTFT/eOj3KijH5sSKRpdUP4AV7WZoRrTx55utoaYKNcM7UFet0wtMwQsYwahVh5WPvZrtkHRVevHcy/P9Xw)

Ungolfed:

```cs
    private static int[][] Blocksort0b(int[][] array, int sortingInstruction)
    {
        if (sortingInstruction < 0) { return array.OrderBy(e => e[-sortingInstruction - 1]).ToArray(); }
        var rowIndices = array[sortingInstruction - 1].Select((value, index) => (value, index)).OrderBy(e => e.value);
        var newRow = new int[array[0].Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            int horizontalIndexer = 0;
            foreach (var e in rowIndices)
            {
                newRow[horizontalIndexer++] = array[i][e.index];
            }
            array[i] = newRow.ToArray();
        }
        return array;
    }
```

New all-inline approach; negative answer still orders arrays by element-at-index. Otherwise, a collection of value-index-pair is created of the array-at-index and sorted by value. This effectively creates a collection of indices in order of having-to-be-added. Then for each array, the elements in the predetermined positions are selected. Quite some trimming of code and ugly, ugly, ugly **silently sobs** reuse of input parameters is involved, and there you go ... 142 bytes.

Again, the arrays argument is strictly enforced, adding quite some overhead for .ToArray() calls.

135 bytes claim, eh?! C# 7.2 inferred value-tuples would trim an additional three bytes, but tio.run doesn't allow. Therefor, this is the answer i decided to post for easy verification.

Comment: Nice answer. There are a few small things to golf. `(a,s)=>` can be a currying `a=>s=>`. `(s<0)?` doesn't need the parenthesis, and `-s-1` can be `~s`. [Try it online: **137 bytes**](https://tinyurl.com/y7rjq96d)

Comment: Sweet! I never would've through of letting the function return yet another function to save a character, i am pleasantly surprised. Thanks!

Also a strong case of blatantly overlooking the not operator and parenthesis. I updated the not and parentheses, but will leave you all the honour for the function-returning-function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 95 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List,Data.Func
$n#f=if(n>0)transpose id
=f o sortBy(on(<)\u=u!!(abs n-1))o f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczBCoJAFIXhvU9xoxYK16gsK8gWUUHgInBpLm7qxIBzR5wx8OWbBHffvzinbGpip3TVNzUokuykanVnIbPVjb94JUvLVBo76d5z6S14LhIpfD6vAtsRm1abGmTlJQI0mHF9GXzN/il49Uk/m/n0NsDhOgg0CJdZGu8TWEAYQZ7v8IB7jAvM1xjhBrejjhiPXhWF@5WioY9x4SN114FJyXKKZ0NW6E79AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>190</s> 185 bytes

```
func[b n][t: func[a][c: length? a/1 a: to[]form a
d: copy[]loop c[append/only d extract a c take a]d]d: does[if n > 0[b: t b]]d
m: absolute n sort/compare b func[x y][x/(m) < y/(m)]d b]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY69bsMwDIR3P8WNzVA4dn7cCEXzDl0JDvpzW9QWBVkB7Kd3lXbJUsATj@B3d0zere/eEVe9WvtbsGQQmLLC76KZrMLgw0f@vELXDbRCFuJe0ghdOQUrcSEeRCIKH6MPrpYwLHDwc07aZmhYZP3todlxsTjxE331CHjDnkxJhGF21aigzSTDLftymyTl2soYdfIwf//MWJjm@mnc4RXLfbIr3jUmMR49iE54QYczgxoc0OJY1AXnovfMeD5Um9HjZrTdTD7WN2jLrTD3sseIDidc0P0T0aw/)

### Explanation:

```
f: func [ b n ] [
    t: func [ a ] [                            ; helper transpose function 
        c: length? a/1                         ; c is the length of the rows
        a: to-block form a                     ; flatten the list
        d: copy []                             ; an empty block (list)
        loop c [                               ; do as many times as the number of columns  
            append/only d extract a c          ; extract each c-th element (an entire column)
                                               ; and append it as a sublist to d
            take a                             ; drop the first element
        ] 
        d                                      ; return the transposed block (list of lists)
    ]
   d: does [ if n > 0 [ b: t b ] ]             ; a helper function (parameterless) to transpose 
                                               ; the array if positive n
   d                                           ; call the function  
   m: absolute n                               ; absolute n
   sort/compare b func[ x y ] [ x/(m) < y/(m) ]; sort the array according to the chosen column 
   d                                           ; transpose if positive n
   b                                           ; return the array  
]
```

My actual solution is 175 bytes long, but it doesn't work in TIO. Here it is, working normalyl in the Red console:

### [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 175 bytes

```
func[b n][d: does[if n > 0[c: length? b/1 a: to-block form b
t: copy[]loop c[append/only t extract a c take a]b: t]]d
m: absolute n sort/compare b func[x y][x/(m) < y/(m)]d b]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 192 bytes

```
{m:Array<Array<Int>>,s:Int->if(s<0){m.sortBy{it[-s-1]}}else{val a=Array(m[0].size){c->Array(m.size){m[it][c]}}
a.sortBy{it[s-1]}
(0..m.size-1).map{r->(0..m[0].size-1).map{m[r][it]=a[it][r]}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vVjdUxs5En/3X9FQe9mZXdvYQGBhA1X52N3KVepIbXJPlB/EjGzrMjOalTQxhPhvz3a3pJkxMYTcVR0PwEj98etPtfRBu0JVX/b24HVVNw6UBVU5uZAG5tqA1cbB1Q0klVwIpz5KXs100ZRVOkAuXcFcGesApcgxvJOZrnL@IFG2FpkEK2thhJM5MRQKiUmIZzN6BYmtZabmN6paQNWUV6hbz4MSO2Y175fK5CBQ9JW8IQ0o3C0JTVHoFTGiIAtJqazFL2IJ/LCQDj5Jo6X9FeS1M6LdEQZBLiptZO61/Euj8eQF01Refi7noikcZMJKOx4Q0UsjyRa2wS0RR6ZzCQtdzE9pe@lcbU/39miVFsfWieyDvM6WolrIcabLvb8aaZ3Sld2bHu9PjibE9tbohRFlSaa8bT59KqSFJ/CSRP@BUojkRaGzDyOKSGsvOSRaoyoQsP8KrTLihpH@gfHqL5JXQ3DtEArpfrQ@wMrZrfKuSKMdk/ctlFKwU4SDG91g4IsbWArMCKe9FAELVkghbZNkCFfoT1HXBYeXfIohqCx6rxTsBKikzIM/o3HKkVT5URoEjTxmUyhhI0nRsDFZ@2eDPmO76cdn80oVBWbMPT5gcwVMR6rK5TVCCBvB4FgHLMTI2kgrK8eKCQ0CRMmEmDjnvB6yF5lrbRXVyxA4TWRE/jBXW2VJ4PLGrxC30Q2iJc@vROXSMfx2Lcq6kKdtmA@vDyDhMF7HIKbBaGLLROXjRHKtr9MAaqXcEgWM9pF80ZRkZdDvuO7I3EBz0JIELwVJLSN7q6LQkaFUeOxmSjFxZVGfk/BRFI28Q7ngsiKtogoOM@jxGoVTRuQKpVvMFwogbXeBp5@Lxm3Eu7D6vqCzIex2n3d305FyVdG67ty1JbHH8LxAvBXHq@hc/J8Gu9rKKCc7mCTr3ftXF/9@3wJ@T8H1oD0JQ/f1RPHhjkgwNhM/Jg7G22bSu0abnHL2n6S40qwXa3S1RMQEisxkY1aiBrfSId1Cw0DxQ9a4WupCtsWP3Eb2ktNCETFS@qKoGpsmPMfIPlJRbAedLk7VxynqqtqnBnZjkrpaqszH0oqyrSNiEYYyE1NLFOAwdWxsGah0b0spMi4jO8WBlxOW0wIL2qorhC0yzEx2PApga0KBebuXIb2xw3Iq5LrjKG667MPcdpSX5IW96PYAKVpNZocy953tbegqaE2uMrSKmmbbudvu0d8NopH9p8HlU4BfAI4BjuAbP5dTwFqHfYDDAXT/g882GglG2G0OTOwhKcBodA5wwrKRejLo/T/7lroO2GzwXTD7@rbDPITkEH2@CbNv3f8D5lOmQ@qjTZg9oPuQ7Fdc7xEkw9xn6u@DecJ0R0T6fTCPIsyn98IMUd@AeRhhTr8L5iTCPCGY3tbH5KUnuyR0A8Y468c7@HEz3oEM64F9OhtAcqXpQDNcripPEcExB/iEfdAJnHbxO@bdze@7jkqmfqpNwWudRveQ7gP@mDLwrxwVnAneJd49s/g98VGdDX7aG4SB2EIYPkc0Zw6xV0FJZw21wyV1NQTCsym1ASmwUxY4gjZiQW2u2gndpcbOQdNXU2Wud7wWorzKxXiA61Abjd3EJnhCGnV9Cs/pwHrmf7@u3Pn5kLvoKbZnl8LtYABA94l52/V5e8jHY2N9t79qVIGjHk6Vbqlzz9E/cbmp4bEbp8F2gsKZNRdOeA5hu4ZL7AHpGHdxtkpY2jOYECjyozdgTMsvbuBWuUsep0fT2TqAvqBjYKUszm2KxmM@ID0qdG87KpBWz@BFDjftosPGm0xtuakRcCDnmc6ohapEQSjXIAvk9PDQjDAMnHkfB49fTmZjqz5JNCMbnQ9iKfRJ4n5gUG52mc3Wa6b1k1LP6NZmztfJeNyTMZqm@FnDrRmdd1sRAe626j1Z2Dcz0om4WRnrN17/msxW8wH/DfHh1HulbF2EfA0AONtyv35/tnUp9jsedCFbzYLS3SdCOOqjUHKswa9rhIenBJcDzclE52m8UbzeSqASDrZSKvn1cxLTucDL5K0W0aIxPNnBEjWUDVadvwR/BdMzGPlXo3AWoOz182AEXMhqgR3qjJoqTTo4eiSkcOesS2hP8/PPg4hmD8kn0evMFIBt8/ZWVwTJ9zqjNjhJJ7v/@OHWK1/nu2M/PXvy1BMyWVElaQSDNIP@Mi@GWPvbqvRljpVksPJ8@6JBD5GEvOlfya3PllKoKkG32pgo79CKatFLkjfcyboGx0PRUhQEX3pnF1DDmaeenuxj00flX27L068bnT3Fv6NzNU/ss0l6W4ay8q2EampN9XzLlXwWCrQtX6resBYWyq5SRU8USxpw@fWLsq3JXjnyehnq70y0lbdef2F73uMNehE827l0bnTZOpt84JCMHcZMf0qR9zKlfQWiZEUZ2O6la2oQkb590@nx8EOKb4AmiIvkmN1KN/7JYdx2PlZyxsRvVCWTdGdn7DS6O0k7Gg6uRbKycQKn8Teo@WIegx4oceS@DdlKTPwY1RfcK2vew4qqGpz7nzzxr1ih8s6xztpSD5rHIs@Zye@sY2F@U060/fU83DTotq/b48MtqQrxfJTXmawpT71j@BQLqinicHbWofJMrzGTF6J4Hi7gv0UBye4Lkfsw7Ox2AGKZdc9vdJzS6baSfELPuYVF8raTieqmux1KvqnG2Jlw40EnB6ycoHiNxkYBu@FAaV2pXIzrugss2xbksKV3PHY3BzHI0lY/YtrhdKAbE6kf5VDONHQkfP7cDQkUNh4HMGD@NP38ucWchA2mikS9uKT/U0xe6gqvmz4u/gESuySdByb26ti/I0d/jmhtDm95vujyrxnmqlJ2icMettO8ydz4nqljwzCcBNCg3tjxVaxx/3HR/jWID6OMHw17kik2YfVZPxW6KozaLz3ZrN2grtujmoTRJx43uxfBV6e7oUWEIYMNDyeW//Bu3DzEdt/5ZxdMvx940t0uJYyQvZzDmVfj7V3QC0iVbxxjoQl6nvjM3HZo64fDTDgcIBJpjDanOPOjq6nrpb1e/bKvAE81jTySU2dTWM@aNgdpbOXHtXCk7ux2rZa7QpjnLubJ3b9Ph/DLEI6HcJQOW8fHzekQDoawP4TDdNguniAtr0/SLSw91v0eE4l5iBwBIBIUffzfwOisJV/ZLeZOhjA62CKa1vtSJ5uw8fNgO6BRnwyhTdOuDfwe72mOD9ms0JXcPIbpKhQaX2Siw73UOT8WjjfGvLv9IXJsaxMP9AeeBDmXaK4mP6W949W0vYMS5pL2sfnHwtzsK@Ei0u8qYadXuv4C0d14/Df1GJptQl0/UNlba7tX3YxwOkvvyumV@G2gWT8oszfV8r84QvmhlkbSL38D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```ruby
->a,n{f=->x{[0,x.transpose,x][n<=>0]};f[f[a].sort_by{|x|x[n.abs-1]}]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpBCsMgEEDRfU/hAUYxMU1bWr3IMBQDNauaoBYMiWe3Wbp7H374TVuddeXGgt@d5ibvKCGLFKyP6xI/kAn9SxtJ5enQoSURl5De07Yf@cjohZ0i76hQqV@bmGaIV7jDDUYC7EBBD8OpB4ynJdFlZTOeJzCu2hia6Bsrqn8)

Answer (score 0):

## VBA (Excel), 205 bytes

Yay! 2nd longest byte count! I didn't completely lose :D

Golfed:

```vb
Sub d(a)
With ActiveSheet.Sort
  .SortFields.Clear
  .SortFields.Add Key:=IIf(a<0,ActiveSheet.Columns(Abs(a)),ActiveSheet.Rows(Abs(a)))
  .SetRange ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  .Orientation=IIf(a<0,1,2)
  .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

This sorts all the data on the open (active) worksheet using UsedRange... which can be buggy, but should only contain cells that have been edited.

UnGolfed:

```vb
Sub d(a)
  'Clear any Sort preferences that already exists
  ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
  'Use the column if A is negative, the row if A is positive
  ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=IIf(a < 0, ActiveSheet.Columns(Abs(a)), ActiveSheet.Rows(Abs(a)))
  'Set the area to sort
  ActiveSheet.Sort.SetRange ActiveSheet.UsedRange
  'Orient sideways if sorting by row, vertical if by column
  ActiveSheet.Sort.Orientation = IIf(a < 0, xlTopToBottom, xlLeftToRight)
  'Actually sort it now
  ActiveSheet.Sort.Apply
End Sub
```

Comment: If you assume that the activesheet is sheet1, then you can get this down to 169 bytes as `Sub d(a)`
`With Sheet1.Sort`
`.SortFields.Clear`
`.SortFields.Add IIf(a<0,Columns(Abs(a)),Rows(Abs(a)))`
`.SetRange Sheet1.UsedRange`
`.Orientation=(a<0)+2`
`.Apply`
`End With`
`End Sub`

Comment: Also, I think that you can safely assume that there are no `.SortFields` Defined so you can remove the `.Sortfields.Clear` line as well.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 43 bytes

```perl6
{($!=$_>0??&[Z]!!*[])o*.sort(*[.abs-1])o$!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvhCoIwFEZf5U6G3I27oWlWhPkeLRGDBkW52Poj0bOv6a@Pcw7f@@afTXzNkFto4xc5a/lwKrouN@eeMWl64aQOzn9QGj1egyqT4ewXwziDRT4IRNwS7Al2BI0gwJKgItgQ1Asdkl1FIYTQD3efMLtMWUrLgHUeVKqqXi/VMf4B)

Curried function.

#### Explanation

```perl6
{                                         } # Block returning function composed of
                                       o$!  # 1. Apply $! (transpose or not)
                     o*.sort(*[.abs-1])     # 2. Sort rows by column abs(i)-1
     $_>0??&[Z]                             # 3. If i > 0 transpose matrix
               !!*[]                        #    Else identity function
 ($!=               )                       #    Store in $!
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Physica](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Physica), 45 bytes

Very similar to [Arnauld's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172067/594870).

```
F=>n;m:n<0&&Sort[->u:u{~n};m]||Zip@F#Zip@m#-n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8ioLM5MTvz/383WLs861yrPxkBNLTi/qCRa167UqrS6Lq/WOje2piYqs8DBTRlE5irr5v0PKMrMK4l2i9Y1tq6uNrW2sDa3Nqu1rja0NrY2sjYBsiytzYBsg9ra2Nj/AA)

#### How it works?

A more elaborate and visual explanation can be found in the linked answer.

```swift
F=>n;m:           // Create a function F that takes two arguments, n and m.
       n<0&&      // If n < 0 (i.e. is negative)
Sort[->u{~n};m]   // Sort the rows u of m by the result of the function u[~n].
                  // In short, sort by indexing from the end with n.
||    F#Zip@m#-n  // Else, apply F to Zip[m] and -n. Uses a new feature, binding.
  Zip@            // And transpose the result.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
f=.[/:({"1~<:)
g=.(f&.|:|)`f@.(0<])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WL1rfSqNaybDOxkqTK91WTyNNTa/GqkYzIc1BT8PAJlbzPxdXanJGvkKurZ6CsYKJgoqCqYKChYKCuYKCmYKCoQJQUMFIASihYAkWAXINIDrU1blgehXSFQzhgnCheMP/AA)

Note: The `g=.` of the main verb doesn't count.

### An explicit version for the same bytes

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 32 bytes

```
4 :'y(]/:{"1)&.(|:^:(x<0))~<:|x'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P91Wz0TBSr1SI1bfqlrJUFNNT6PGKs5Ko8LGQFOzzsaqpkL9PxdXanJGvkKurZ6CsYKJgoqCqYKChYKCuYKCmYKCoQJQUMFIASihYAkWAXINIDrU1bmgeo0U0hVy4YJgOh4s9h8A)

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 91 bytes

```
(fn f[A i](if(< i 0)(sort-by #(nth %(- -1 i))A)(apply map list(f(apply map list A)(- i)))))
```

Argh, `apply map list` * 2.